# Python: Count divisible numbers from a smaller number WITHOUT string

Tags: python, math

Say you have a function:

```
def count_divisible_numbers(n, m):
    ...
```

This function should calculate how many digits in `n` are evenly divisible by `m`.

For example:

```
>>> n = 668593
>>> m = 3
>>> count_divisible_numbers(n, m)
4
```

BECAUSE 6, 6, 9, and 3 of `6668593` (n) are divisible by 3 (m).

You can't use str to break apart `n` into individual parts, and you can ONLY use pythons built-in variables / functions (no imports) WITHOUT recursion.

**How would you define this function to get it to produce that result?**

NOTE: I'm a self-taught Python programmer who's bulit packages and web apps before, and this was a problem that a student of mine that was in college had that I couldn't figure out how to solve, and it annoyed me.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems relatively simple using mod and division.

Comment: "You can't use str..." -- you can get around these arbitary requirements using `repr()` ;)

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're not wrong  but only because I was totally stumped. I knew it had something to do with modulus and floor division, but I couldn't find any answer on Google for this specific of a problem. The case for using this (to me at least) only seemed to be for this arbitrary college class lesson. I haven't had to use modulus / floor division at all in any of my applications. Maybe I should  lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the ones-place of `n` by taking the modulus of 10, then use that value to check if evenly divisible by `m`. Then integer-divide by 10 to move all the digits "over" to work on the next number that is now in the ones-place.

```
def count_divisble_numbers(n, m):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        if (n%10) % m == 0:
            total += 1
        n //= 10
    return total

>>> count_divisble_numbers(668593, 3)
4
```

Comment: Do we care about negative n? OP might not.

Comment: WOW! I'm not sure why that seems so complicated to me  I guess I was just never really had a use case scenario with modulus OR floor division.